# Tkinter lable config dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

i want dynamic lable.config is it possible ? because the result doesn't fix with the screen size and the rest of the text are cut off and cannot see. Here is the code. i know my code is not effective but i am a beginner and i have no idea and dont know anything about GUI in python

```
def link_GUI(graph):
    def btn_click():
        data1 = str(txtDataEntry.get())  # get data from test box
        data2 = str(txtDataEntry2.get())
        r_edge = link(graph, data1, data2)
        lblResult.config(text="" + data1 + " and " + data2 + " are linked")
        lblResult2.config(text="" + str(r_edge))
    root = Tk()
    root.title("SSM Application")
    root.geometry("1500x600")
    lblTitle = Label(text=" Link a station to another station", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), fg='Black')
    lblTitle.pack()
    lblTitle = Label(text=" *Close the box to choose another option*  ", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), fg='Black')
    lblTitle.pack()
    frame1 = Frame()

    lblDataentry = Label(frame1, text="Enter first station name:", pady=1, fg='black')  # 1111111111111111
    lblDataentry.grid(row=0, column=0)
    txtDataEntry = Entry(frame1)  # 111111111111111
    txtDataEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    lblDataentry = Label(frame1, text="Enter second station name:", pady=1, fg='black')  # 2222222222222
    lblDataentry.grid(row=1, column=0)
    txtDataEntry2 = Entry(frame1)  # 222222222222222
    txtDataEntry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    btnSubmit = Button(frame1, text="Link", bg='grey', fg='black', command=btn_click)
    btnSubmit.grid(row=2, column=1)
    frame1.pack()  # add frame to gui
    lblResult = Label(font=('arial', 18, 'bold'), fg='darkblue')
    lblResult.pack()
    lblResult2 = Label(font=('arial', 18, 'bold'), fg='darkblue')
    lblResult2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

the original output result[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErzL6.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErzL6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErzL6.png)

here is the result after i tried with wrap length but it also cannot help too is there any other ways to do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3eBd.png

Comment: Have you tried setting the `wraplength` option of the Label widget?

Comment: Setting `wraplength` will wrap the text into multiple lines if the width (in pixel) of the text is longer than the specify `wraplength`.  Is it what you want?

Comment: yes @acw1668 how can i do it sir

Comment: this gui cut off rest of the text and it only display in the fix length. i want to see all of the text

Comment: i tried with wavelength but it cannot also help me https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3eBd.png is there any other way to do?

Comment: sir it doesn't help too. can i do another way ? is it possible to output with scroll bar ? @acw1668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change `root.geometry("1500x600")` to `root.minsize(1500, 600)` in order to let the root window to expand.
2. change `lblResult2.pack()` to `lblResult2.pack(fill="both", expand=1)`, so that `lblResult2` will fill the root window width and adjust the root window height in order to show all its content.
3. change `lblResult2.config(text=""+str(r_edge))` to `lblResult2.config(text=str(r_edget), wraplength=lblResult2.winfo_width(), justify='left')` in order to wrap its content to fit its width.

**Edit:** *Another solution is to use `Text` widget instead of `Label`*:

1. change the following lines

   ```
   lblResult2 = Label(font=('arial', 18, 'bold'), fg='darkblue')
   lblResult2.pack()
   ```

   to

   ```
   txtResult2 = Text(font=('arial', 18, 'bold'), fg='darkblue')
   txtResult2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
   ```
2. change the following line in `btn_click()`:

   ```
   lblResult2.config(text=""+str(r_edge))
   ```

   to

   ```
   txtResult2.delete(1.0, 'end')
   txtResult2.insert('end', str(r_edge))
   ```

Comment: sir it doesn't help too. can i do another way ? is it possible to output with scroll bar ?

Comment: What do you mean _"doesn't help"_? Is it too big to fit into screen height?  If it is, then better use `Text` widget instead.

Comment: yes yes too big to fit into screen height. for text widget which code should i change sir @acw1668

Comment: you are the best man you are so kind thanks a lot <3 @acw1668